# Understanding a couple of regex expressions

Tags: regex

I have a couple of regex expressions that I don't understand.

Why doesn't `[^dp]an` match the string `'pan'`? I thought the regex was telling you to match any substring that contains 'd' or 'p', then 'an'. But it doesn't seem like that's what it's saying.

Also, am I interpreting `<[a-z]*@\w+.edu>` correctly: match characters in [a-z] 0 more times until you reach '@', then match any word character 1 or more times, then match any character except new line, then match 'edu'.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: [dp]an will match either dan or pan but [^dp]an will match anything but dan and pan, so it would match lan, van, tan etc... and your interpretation of the second regex is spot on.

Answer (score 2):

`[^` means DON'T match characters in the set.  Or, more accurately, match any character but characters in that set (so a character does have to be there.)

Regarding the next one, you are basically correct although missing <> which that regex also needs for a match to occur.  What `.` means actually depends, but it *usually* means any character but a newline.  Sometimes it can include a newline (perl, in special modes, for example)

And this may be of use to you, as it breaks down what each bit means:
https://regex101.com/